# Split string by multiple delimiters and keeping some delimiters while discarding others

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I would like to split by the space string `" "` while removing it and also
split by a comma `","` while keeping it.

```
var str = "This is a word, and another."
var regexKeepCommaDelimeter = new RegExp(/(,)/,'g')
var regexKeepCommaRemoveSpace = new RegExp(/(????)/,'g')
var splitArray = str.split(regexKeepCommaRemoveSpace)
var desiredArray = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'word', ',', 'and', 'another.' ]
var testPassed = splitArray.every((x,i)=> x == desiredArray[i])
console.log('Arrays match:', testPassed)
```

Comment: Re `console.log(splitArray == desiredArray)` -- Just a side note that one array is never `==` a different array, even if they have the same entries in them.

Comment: I just noticed this. how peculiar. :)

Comment: @TimarIvoBatis - Not at all. :-) With objects, equality is about whether they're the **same** object, not equivalent objects.

Comment: Didn't spend much time thinking about the test writing the question. Sometimes you just hope for javascript coercion to do things haha
Updated the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the space, and match and *capture* the comma when splitting with `str.split(/\s+|(,)/).filter(Boolean)`.

Or, you may match any amount of chars other than whitespace and commas, or just a comma with `str.match(/[^\s,]+|,/g)`.

```js
var str = "This is a word, and another.";
console.log(
  str.split(/\s+|(,)/).filter(Boolean)
);
// => ["This", "is", "a", "word", ",", "and", "another."]

console.log(
  str.match(/[^\s,]+|,/g)
);
// => ["This", "is", "a", "word", ",", "and", "another."]
```

The `.filter(Boolean)` part will remove empty items from the resulting array that appear due to eventual consecutive matches, or matches at the start of the string.

Comment: Fantastic idea with the str.match!

Comment: @TimarIvoBatis Yes, but that is only good for cases when you have a single char string that you need to get separately. When one have a multi-character string, one should consider the `split` approach.

Comment: I don't follow. you mean when i want to remove multiple delimiters or keep multiple delimiters? Seems to work fine in both cases for me.

Comment: @TimarIvoBatis Yes, both will work for you. But in case you want to have some `abc_123` from `...@abc_123@...` as a separate item, you can't just tell `String#match` to skip the `@\w+@` pattern. `str.split(/@(\w+)(?=@)|\s+/).filter(Boolean)` would be necessary then (well, this is a fake scenario, just to illustrate).

Comment: Ah, so you mean if I wanted to use multi-character-delimiters?
This is an edge case so far outside, Im still having trouble to follow. So I think its good enough :)

Answer (score 3):

One fairly simple approach would be to add spaces around any `,` that don't have them, then just split on space:

```
var splitArray = str.replace(/ ?, ?/g, " , ").split(" ");
```

Live Example:

```js
var str = "This is a word, and another."
var splitArray = str.replace(/ ?, ?/g, " , ").split(" ");
console.log(splitArray);
var desiredArray = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'word', ',', 'and', 'another.' ];
console.log(splitArray.every((e, i) => e === desiredArray[i]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```